# adding flash in swing components

Tags: java, flash, swing

I am creating a swing application, I like to add Flash in that application. Can we add flash in Swing components?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should stick to one of both technologies. For example use Flash with ASwing. Or Java with a suitable library to replace the features you need from Flash.
Unless you have a very good reason not to, you should always try to use the least platforms possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at JavaFX, which allows easier and nicer (than Swing) graphical interactions and animations and integrates nicely with swing.

I don't have any personal experience with JavaFX but a colleague of mine is working on a project that shows the way to the different rooms and buildings in our organization on a map, using a touch screen for input. He uses JavaFX for the GUI and Java for the backend programming, and he is quite satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

[JXBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/index.jsf) is a non-free option ?

Starting from version 2.0, the library allows integration of Microsoft Internet Explorer, Apple Safari (WebKit) and Mozilla Firefox (Gecko) engines for rendering HTML web pages, thus ensuring compliance with many Internet standards (HTML 4, CSS, XML, JavaScript, Adobe Flash, and others).

---

[There is a Java Flash Player also](https://jflash.dev.java.net/).